# Event bind to the dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one textbox#search_text. on keyup i create one div#sresult_container.and append to some div to div#sresult_container. i try to bind click and mouseover event to  div#sresult_container when this container display on canvas. i try following code but that not work.How can i do?

```
$("#search_text").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 40 && e.which != 38) {
        $("#search").removeAttr('disabled');
        $.post('http://www.allinone.com', {
            Search: sVal
        }, function(data) {
            $sresult_container = $('<div id="sresult_container"></div>');
            //somecode which create another divs and append to the $sresult_container
        })
    }

    $('#sresult_container').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            //some code  
            },
            mouseover: function(e) {
                //some code
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Be careful the `.live()` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `.on()` or `'.delegate()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can do this task with "[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)" function.

```
$('#sresult_container').live('click', function() {
    alert('hello from binded function call');
});
```

Comment: No my friend. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. [Read here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#someParent').on('click', '.someChildSelector', function(e){
});
```

Listen for `click` events that bubble up to `#someParent` that match the specified(i.e. `.someChildSelector`) selector.

So events originating from any child elements that you have appended will be caught by the above handler.

Comment: @RVSharepoint: That's not the point. A revenge down-vote doesn't help anybody. That's like saying - **nobody will ever update their version of jQuery.**

Comment: yes i told you same thing.. its also helpful for some people :)

Comment: @RVSharepoint: Which is why he has chosen your answer I guess :) I  don't agree it's the best solution, therefore, I chose to down-vote. But it doesn't explain your down-vote. Against the spirit of this community, my friend. Have a good day.

Comment: But i have also use live function in latest jquery 1.8. its working fine for me. have a good day :)